# How to manually deploy a CLR stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I created a CLR stored procedure:

```
public class StoredProcedures
{
    [SqlProcedure]
    public static void InsertProduct(SqlString param1, SqlString param2, SqlString param3)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled and managed to add the assembly in SQL server:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Assembly.Namespace] FROM 'path here';
```

But what is the SQL syntax to create a SQL procedure that maps to this CLR stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example C in [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY HandlingLOBUsingCLR
FROM '\\MachineName\HandlingLOBUsingCLR\bin\Debug\HandlingLOBUsingCLR.dll';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetPhotoFromDB
(
    @ProductPhotoID int,
    @CurrentDirectory nvarchar(1024),
    @FileName nvarchar(1024)
)
AS EXTERNAL NAME HandlingLOBUsingCLR.LargeObjectBinary.GetPhotoFromDB;
GO
```